# Stripes over the SVG when moving an element in Safari

Tags: javascript, html, svg, safari

When I try to move a child div on top of an SVG, the SVG starts to have weird vertical stripes. This only happens on Safari (I tested on iPad, iPhone, Mac, PC both Chrome and Safari).

To see the bug, position your cursor over the image, and move to the right. If it doesn't appear, please just shorten the width of the screen.

[Reproduction of this bug (vercel.app)](https://missing-bug.vercel.app/)

[GIF Preview - This is how appears](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK2hf.gif)

```js
    function App() {
      const [delta, setDelta] = useState(0);
    
      const handleTouchMove = (event) => {
        let delta = event.touches[0].clientX;
        setDelta(delta);
      };
    
      const handleMouseMove = (event) => {
        let delta = event.clientX + 40;
        setDelta(delta);
      };
    
    
      return (
        <div
          style={{
            background: "#5f5fc4",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            alignItems: "center",
            border: "1px solid #413793"
          }}
        >
          <svg
            width="500"
            height="500"
            onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            style={{ background: "#283593" }}
          >
            <g>
              <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500">
                <picture>
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    width="100%"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/h1vMJwO.png"
                  />
                </picture>
              </foreignObject>
            </g>
          </svg>
            <div style={{ width: delta, background: "#001064", color: "white", fontSize: '1.2rem' }}>
              Another div here with {delta}px.
            </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

[Repository of this specific bug](https://github.com/marcelobitorical/SVG-Stripes-bug/blob/main/src/App.js)

This bug is definitely specific to Safari: However, from personal experience, I have seen this behavior through other projects where the browser is not a problem for the bug to appear. But I can't find a solution or an explanation.

**How can I fix it, or at least why does it happen?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Very interesting case.
I have a fix, but I don't know why it happen. Probably safari rendering issue.

1. remove `align-items:center` from wrapper
2. remove `background-color:#001064;` from inner div and add `display: flex; align-items: center;`
3. add another div as text wrapper and set again background color `background-color:#001064;` and add `width:100%`.

```
...
  <div
          style={{
            background: "#5f5fc4",
            display: "flex",
            justifyContent: "center",
            border: "1px solid #413793"
          }}
        >
          <svg
            width="500"
            height="500"
            onTouchMove={handleTouchMove}
            onMouseMove={handleMouseMove}
            style={{ background: "#283593" }}
          >
            <g>
              <foreignObject x="0" y="0" width="500" height="500">
                <picture>
                  <img
                    alt=""
                    width="100%"
                    src="https://i.imgur.com/h1vMJwO.png"
                  />
                </picture>
              </foreignObject>
            </g>
          </svg>
            <div style={{ width: delta, color: "white", fontSize: '1.2rem', display:"flex", alignItems:"center" }}>
               <div style={{width:"100%",background: "#001064"}}>
                 Another div here with {delta}px.
               </div>
            </div>
        </div>
...
```